# How to use Twitter Streaming API?

Tags: python, api, twitter, automation, tweepy

I been successfully able to use Twitter REST API to do find tweets and retweet them automatically. Now I want to tweet user a **Thank You Message**, I am using Python and Tweepy for my BOT. I can do live collection of tweets, using Twitter Streaming API, but I can't understand how to use the API to send a thank you message to those who favorite my tweets. I saw both the documentations but couldn't understand and use much from there. I also tried to search for any example but couldn't find any good one for Streaming API.

Can anyone show me how to use it with tweepy to achieve the same. It would be nice if you can show how to use it when someone retweets my tweet or follows me, I want to send them a thank you tweet automatically.

PS: I understand that Twitter doesn't likes much automation. But its all for learning.

Comment: Twitter loves automation, there is an API exactly for these reasons.  They mainly don't want you building shittier mobile clients.